# SignalR stops working in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to build the project in this link : 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

It works as expected in Chrome, but in Firefox there is a problem.
If I open more than three tabs of Firefox, signalR stops working and will work only for the first three tabs.

Is this a really problem ?

Comment: It might be because chrome every tab is a separate process where as in firefox all tabs and windows run under the same process. It could be max threads per process issue

Comment: This is probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser